# Error when trying to load the array package

Tags: packages, arrays

I am writing my thesis paper in Math and I really need to use the [array package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array). But when I wrote `\usepackage{array}` an error occurred. It says `"pdflatex> ! Emergency stop."` What should be the right one to use?

Comment: Try to make [a MWE that replicates the problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Often preparing a MWE already solves the problem before it reaches to this site :) Otherwise, we can only say that line is correct and it should have worked.

Comment: What is an MWE? I am sorry, I am still a beginner in latex.

Comment: Click the link in percusse's comment to know MWE :)

Comment: Common errors that lead to this are not closing `}` above, mistyping some package name/option, misplacing the whole line, too many/too little `\\`. Some (oldish) packages react badly if you give several options separated by commas and spaces.